# Integral of a derivate of F(x)?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am having trouble solving this lab question:

If the function G(x) is the derivative of the function F(x), then the integral of G(x) is equal to which of the following?

A. Some number plus the derivative of the square of F(x)

B. Some number plus G(x)

C. Some number plus G(x) multiplied by F(x)

D. Some number plus G(x) divided by F(x)

I think the answer is C or D but I have no way of knowing if I am right. 
I tried this problem with a sample equation $F(x)= x^2$ and $G(x)$ would be $2x$.
Taking the integral of $G(x)$ gets you $C + x^2$ but none of the answer choices seem to match up. Any help is appreciated

Comment: By "integral', you mean [primitive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative), right ?  If so, then the antiderivative of $G$ has the form $x\mapsto F(x)+c$

Comment: The correct answer is "E. Some number plus F(x)" (obviously the problem is flawed!).

Comment: As Lærne and  Lovsovs also point out, the correct answer is not listed... It should be `some number plus F(x)'

Comment: Congratulations on finding an example that shows the defect in the lab question. It shows you were thinking about what you were doing. (It's not so clear what the person who wrote the problem was thinking ... .)

Answer (score 1):

None of those are right, as the comments are mentioning (I also have no idea what was intended).

If $G(x)=F'(x)$, then we can integrate both sides using the FTC
$$
\int G(x)=\int F'(x)=F(x)+c
$$